# Странная ошибка jquery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Делаю небольшой сайт, этакий минимаркет по продаже букетов [вот](http://shop.astormedia.ru/), на главной странице всё работает отлично, а на внутренних (в карточках товара) любая библиотека jquery выдаёт ошибку "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /
.../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", многочисленное сравнение страниц, поочерёдное отключение скриптов, подключение разных библиотек ничего не дают. Кнопка купить в карточке товара не работает. Что делать ума не приложу =( 
Строка: 3

Comment: Попробуйте сменить версию jQuery.

Comment: читайте внимательней вопрос "...любая библиотека jquery выдаёт ошибку ..." и "...подключение разных библиотек ничего не дают..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в функции `initScrollNav` в строке

```
nav.each(function (){
        var hold = jQuery(this);
        var block = jQuery(hold.attr('href'));    // вот тут
        ...
    });
```

Когда вы обрабатываете ссылки навигации, первой у вас идёт ссылка "Главная", у которой атрибут `href = "/"`. Поэтому строка `var block = jQuery(hold.attr('href'));` превращается в `var block = jQuery('/');`. `/` не является валидным селектором jQuery, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! Подскажите а как Вы ошибку эту идентифицировали? У вас есть спец софт? (у меня только firebug и прочая ерунда встроенная в браузеры)

Comment: Той самой "встроенной в браузер ерундой". В данном случае - Chrome Developer Tools. Обычно при возникновении ошибки в консоль пишется стек вызовов, приведших к ошибке. Именно по нему я и определил место, где возникла ошибка, поставил там брейкпоинт и посмотрел, что происходит в функции.